# Creating a linked list without declaring node as a pointer

Tags: c, linked-list

I've been searching around for a good while now on google and a few text books and I can't seem to understand why it is, when building a linked list, that the nodes need to be pointers.

Eg. If i have a node defined as:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

why is it that in order to create a linked list, I would say:

```
Node *a = malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node *b = malloc(sizeof(Node));
a->value = 1;
b->value = 2;

a->next = b;
b->next = NULL;
```

rather than:

```
Node a, b;
a.value = 1;
b.value = 2;

a.next = &b;
b.next = NULL;
```

To my understanding, the list will still be able to be referenced and traversed as normal, the only difference is the use of the dot, ampersand syntax rather than the arrow?

Comment: Your `Node *a, *b` snippet is invalild. You're declaring pointer variables, without having them point to valid memory. The pointers almost certainly won't point to valid `Node` objects

Comment: With your second example, think about how you would add hundreds of new nodes to your list. Using pointers, you can keep using malloc to add new nodes inside a loop. Without pointers, then you're need to allocate storage some other way, somewhat defeating the benefit of using a linked list.

Answer (score 4):

You can create the list in a way that you mentioned.

But you must care for the life time of the list members. If your

> Node a, b;

are in scope of a function then these are lost after the return of that function.

When you use pointers then you usually use the heap and the instances live until they are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example will not work. You are declaring two `Node` pointers. However, since you do not initialize these to anything, it is illegal to deference them, since they don't point to anything. You must first use something like `malloc` to declare memory for them to point to, or assign them to a previously declared local variable. However, you must also remember to call `free` when you are done with the memory.

In the second example, you are declaring two `Node` variables, which you use to store instances of the `Node`. These will be allocated on the stack if they are local variables, and they will live for as long as they are in scope. They hold valid memory, and thus you can use them in the way you have demonstrated.

Comment: My mistake. But under the assumption that i have allocated the required space for a and b, say if i have my two malloc statements underneath "Node *a, *b" for example.. what would be the impending differences at that point between that example of a linked list and the second one that i mentioned?