# Why can't you create a linked lists without creating nodes as pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list

There is an answer in [Creating a linked list without declaring node as a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331173/creating-a-linked-list-without-declaring-node-as-a-pointer). But I wanted to know if there were any other reasons due to which you can't create nodes as pointers, just so, to be clear.

One of the reasons is that the scope of the new nodes will die outside the function-Is there no way you can solve this problem?, and
Is there any other reason?

Comment: You can probably solve the life-time problem if you really want to, but it will be a lot of work, and very easy to get wrong, so why would you want to do it?

Comment: The linked question has a bad title and is actually "why do I need dynamically allocated nodes", not "why do I need pointers".

Comment: You can solve scope problem by using global variables (use `extern`)

Comment: @melk, No, I'm just asking. I just want to know if it's impossible to declares nodes as just objects. Or, if there is a way, how is it more complex, than using pointers. 
For example, Landstalker seems to have given a solution. 
So, just wanted to what are the other problems with using nodes as objects(and not pointers)

Comment: You don't strictly *need* pointers at all. You can store your nodes in an array (or vector, if you want an adjustable amount) and use indices as "node identifiers".

Comment: You can't avoid using some kind of indirection. If a node contains a node, which contains a node, which contains a node, and so on, it fills up the universe and everything blows up.

Comment: The node can just be connected to a node in the usual way. The pointer will still be inside the node, which can point to another node. Isn't it?
I'm not challenging the available methods. I'm just trying to understand 'why not?' I'm also hoping that the first programmers did think of this way and must have chosen using pointers for some reason. Just trying to know what is the reason

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, I know about the array method. Just wanted to know why, not using either of them (pointers/arrays) is a really inefficient method, and why?
Because for any new programmer, I think pointers themselves need an extra step to be understood. 
So if, even then, pointers are used, there must be some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using a lot of linked lists (and even more complex structures) in which no node was allocated separately on the heap but all the nodes were elements in a single array.

Having pointers to nodes and allocating single nodes on the heap is common, but by far not the only option. For example it may be better for certain applications to allocate nodes in "pages" for efficiency or to simplify disposal.

Another option that is quite common and often useful is creating linked lists or trees where there are no pointers at all (not even inside nodes) by using numeric indexes in an array instead. E.g.

```
struct Tree {
    struct Node {
        double value;
        int left, right; // Index of left/right child, -1 if missing
    };
    int root = -1;
    std::vector<Node> nodes;
};
```

Comment: What's the purpose of a linked list if you use an array as underlying storage?

Comment: @Victor how does it matter?

Comment: @Victor: still you can insert and remove elements with the same complexity (e.g. to remove an element requires just adjusting the pointers and is O(1)). If you need to allocate a new node and the array is full you need to do a reallocation, and that's a cost to pay, but individual allocations if there's room in the array are faster than allocating memory on the heap. You also use less memory. A list/tree stored in an array using integers as pointers is easier to serialize to/from disk or to send over a network; there are many cases in which using indexes instead of pointers can be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

A [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) is literally defined as a structure in which objects **point** to one another:

> In computer science, a *linked list* is a linear collection of data elements, whose order is not given by their physical placement in memory. Instead, each element *points* to the next.

In C++, an object can point to another using a pointer or a reference.

A reference is possible but inconvenient, since it must be set at object creation and cannot be modified.

Any other structure in which you can navigate from one object to another without following a pointer would not be a linked list. A typical example is an array: you can navigate to the next element by *computing* its address relative to the current one.

Now *how* you allocate nodes is entirely up to you - you can allocate them in dynamic memory, in automatic storage (on the stack), statically, in shared memory, etc. If they are linked using a pointer or a reference, you'll still have a linked list structure.

Comment: Okay, the objects will contain pointers 'within' them to point to the next objects. Will that be enough to satisfy the definition of a linked list? But why create the 'new node' as a pointer? As in: why `struct node* new_node` instead of `struct node new_node`

Comment: Yes. `node* new_node = new node;` allocates a node on the heap, and `node new_node;` inside a function allocates a node on the stack. If the nodes point to one another, it's still a linked list. Beware though that stack-allocated stuff is automatically released when the function ends. That's why it's more convenient to allocate on the heap.

Comment: okay, so you're telling that the node will not remain anymore, once the control of the program is out of the function?

Comment: okay, so you're telling that the node will not remain anymore, once the control of the program is out of the function?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's called automatic storage - objects are automatically allocated at the beginning of the block scope and released at the end of the scope.

Comment: okay, thank you. But someone mentioned that you can use `extern` to overcome that..

Comment: Yes, `node new_node;` at global scope will have static storage duration, i.e. will never be allocated or released. To reach it from another source file you'll need to declare it with `extern node new_node;`. For more details refer to [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211207/discussion-between-swaroop-joshi-and-rustyx).

Answer (score 0):

Another reason I can think of is that it would be more convenient to traverse the linked list. For example:

```cpp
Node* current;
while (current != nullptr) {
    // Do something
    current = current->next;
}
```

If `current` is not a pointer, you probably will make copies of each node in the link list, which is really a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a linked list in shared memory or reflective memory, then the world of pointers is non existent.  You are back to the 1970s, using array indices instead of pointers.

It is a very different world and a total culture shock for those who are used to pointers.  There is no heap and you have to manage your own garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

**Why can't you create a linked lists without creating nodes as pointers?**

You can but you most definitly need some sort of indirection.

Why are a pointers commonly used to implement linked Lists?
As @6502 already pointed out in his answer you can achieve the same thing by arrays or any other container which you keep as page/memory of the list. But for the sake of the argument lets compare a List implemented by pointers and one with keeps the node as member. The main answer is: It is easier to implement the functionality of a list.
The benefit of Lists is you can easily push/pop front and back and delete items very fast. How is deleting in list done implementation wise? You simply change the pointer which is pointing to the "to be deleted object" to the next node (or in the array case you assign another index). But if your "to be deleted objected" conatins the other Object as real Object and not via pointer you will have to `move` it out of there before deleting it otherwise the it and the rest of the list would be gone.

Also you can only implement a single-linked list, because only one Node can hold the other. If `Node A` has `NodeB` it is not possible that `NodeB`can also have `NodeA`. But with pointers `NodeB` can point to `NodeA` without problems and vice versa.

TL;DR
If you use pointers or arrays your list actions like deleting, pushing and so on are simnply switching pointers or indices. If your nodes contain the data you need to up date these by moving/copying. And this is cumbersome to implement and much harder to grasp than the pointer/reference indirection.