# Why does the actual node have to be a pointer?

Tags: c++

So when we actually create the node object, why does it have to be a pointer. Why cant be just make it a regular Node object, use . for the data and then use the arrow operator for next node.

```
class Node {
      int data;
      Node * next;
};

  int main() {
    Node * node1, node2; // why make it a pointer
    Node node3, node4; // Why dont people leave it has non pointer, 
    because you already have Node* next in the class.
   }
```

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61097899/4117728

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331173/creating-a-linked-list-without-declaring-node-as-a-pointer

Comment: if every `Node` contains a `Node` then every `Node` contains infinite number of nodes. Thats not something you want or that would be possible

Comment: `node2` is a `Node`, not a `Node *`.

Comment: I was a bit too much interpreting into your question (I thought it is about the member). There is no apparent reason why the nodes in `main` are pointers, you could create objects as well.

Comment: Why do you think that there is something wrong with `node2`, `node3` and `node4`. They are fine.

Comment: You don't need a pointer in a node.  You can implement a linked list in an array.  In the case of an array, the location of the `next` node would be an array index, not a pointer.  You'll need a location of the next node because there is no guarantee that the next node will be immediately following the present node.  Run through an insert algorithm and you'll find out why.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers play well with dynamic allocation.  You can continue using the object through pointers until you purposefully free it.  Automatic objects on the other hand, get destroyed at the end of the scope leaving all pointers (and references!<sup>1</sup>) to them dangling.

If you know that you won't use any of the pointers outside the scope that contains the object itself (this is likely true for your example in `main()`), then go right ahead and use an automatic object.

But one final complication is that if one of the pointers is a "smart" pointer that knows how to free the object it points to, you have to create the attached object using the matching allocation function.  Attempting to free an automatic (scoped)<sup>2</sup> object will result only in misery.

---

<sup>1</sup> The oft-repeated statements like "a reference is equivalent to the object itself" and "a well-defined program cannot create an invalid reference" are horribly wrong but that's too long a discussion to have here.

<sup>2</sup> Misery also accompanies trying to free an object which is static or a member subobject or dynamically allocated using a different allocator.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a reference to a place in memory, since each node should reference the other node and not store its value directly, because if it would store a value you need to update it each time the other node is updated. 
One can also use a pointer to allocate memory in the "heap" with the "new" keyword(dynamic storage), otherwise it could be stored in the "stack"(automatic storage), which has a very limited memory(you can get a stack overflow).

Comment: There are more than two storage lifetimes... not every object created without `new` goes on the stack.

Comment: Thats right, I'm just trying to keep the explanation simple. I guess Ill change the "will" with "could"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for some educational purpose.

```
    class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node * next;
        Node(int d, Node *nextNode = NULL) :data(d), next(nextNode) {}
        Node() {}
    };

    int main() {
        Node node3, node4(20); 
        node3.data = 10;
        node3.next = &node4;

        std::cout << node3.data << "   " << node3.next->data << std::endl;
    }
```

But in real world, in creation of linked linked, you don't know when you have to create a list. In your case its a small class, but consider if it a big class with several complex data structure. If you go in this way, unnecessarily you will create a object on stack.

It will also create ambiguity while deleting memory, you will have to take a special care. In fact, you will not be able to remove memory for your first node until execution goes out of memory.

now here is one big issue, **If you are passing this list to some other function(may be creating a list in a function and returning it to caller), this first Node will go out of scope and the memory allocated to your list will be leaked.**

Hope I cleared your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it into a Node object and compile the code. There should be a compilation error saying that it is an incomplete type. This is because the next field is creating an infinite loop and the compiler cannot calculate how big that field is supposed to be.